# CRA to Vite trying to deploy to Heroku - error "{}-cache" is imported by " - blank page

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, vite

Our app run react for the front-end and we are trying to move away from Create React App and use Vite. Locally everything is working just fine but when pushing to Heroku we have the following error in the console and our app is just a blank page. We have tried with different buildpacks, etc. But there is no difference, the heroku logs are clean, no errors and 200s all around. I can see that the app js is served to the browser but we have no more errors than this.

`caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "{}-cache". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

We have tried using different buildpacks (nodeJs and nginx at the moment), changing the setting in procfiles, etc.

Comment: Did you check the error _references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"_? Looks like some import paths don't have the correct references.

Comment: Yes we did and discarded it. We have found the problem now and fixed it. I'll update the question with the solution in a bit